# How to draw SVG polygon with a list of colors (like glColorPointer inOpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, svg

I'm translating OpenGL drawing code to SVG. One feature OpenGL has is that when drawing a closed line (or polygon) you can specify a color for each vertex:

```
short vertices[100*3] = {100, 100, 100, 102, 102, 102, ....};
glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, vertices); // give vertices to OpenGL
char colors[100*3] = {255, 0, 0, 254, 0, 0,....};
glColorPointer(m_3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, pColors);// give color to OpenGL
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 100);
```

This will make the fill color change according to the distance from each point.

In SVG I can specify only a single fill color for a polygon:

```
<polygon points="0 524 0 509 5 509 5 524" stroke="#000000" fill="#453d3b" stroke-width="8.00000px"/>
```

Is there a way to to achieve this effect with SVG?

Comment: "*This will make the fill color change according to the distance from each point.*" No, it won't. It will cause the color to be interpolated within the *triangles* that the polygon is broke up into. That's not the same thing as the *distance* to each point.

Comment: OK, point taken. What about SVG?